# Trying to install webpack cli but I am getting multiple errors

Tags: webpack

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF8Cb.jpg) I am trying to run es6 on vs. I bought a course on udemy that is teaching me this. However, I have to install webpack, config it to use bable. I have been trying to move on from this process. However, I am having a massive problem with installing webpack from the terminal. Here is an error I am getting. Don't know what the issue could be. I even tried typing sudo in front it with no luck. I have attached the image! It would be clearer this way

Comment: What version of node and npm do you have?
node -v and npm -v

Comment: @Miguel node 8.11.2 and npm 5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your command, I see that you're trying to run

npm i webpack-cli@3.0.3 --save dev

If you want to save the dependency to your devDependencies you have to use **--save-dev** (With the dash)